# PostgreSQL trigger won't inset audit value

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I'm working with PostgreSQL 8.1 and I created a trigger for a table, so if something gets updated or inserted it will be also registered in a log table, but I'm having issues with NULL values:

If I update a column with a NULL value, then it won't insert any value to the log, but with char to char it will be fine, so maybe I'm missing something.

The table was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log_test(

    id_test         integer   NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_test_seq'),
    type         char(3),
    product         char(10),
    table             char(15),
    field            char(10),
    old_val            char(10),
    new_val            char(10),
    user            char(10),
    event            char(10),
    date           timestamp with time zone      NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
 CONSTRAINT "log_test_prim" PRIMARY KEY ("id_test")
);
```

The trigger was created like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "public"."log_test_trigger" () RETURNS "trigger" AS 'BEGIN
...
   IF (TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
            IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name) THEN
                   INSERT INTO log_test (type, table, field, old_val, new_val, user, event) VALUES (NEW.type,  TG_RELNAME, ''name'', OLD.name, NEW.name, NEW.user, ''UPDATE'');
            END IF;
...
END;' LANGUAGE "plpgsql"
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare `NULL` to a value, i.e. both `NULL = 2` and `NULL <> 2` are `NULL`. Add `ISNULL`:

```
...
IF (TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
    IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name OR NEW.name ISNULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO log_test (type, table, field, old_val, new_val, user, event) VALUES (NEW.type,  TG_RELNAME, ''name'', OLD.name, NEW.name, NEW.user, ''UPDATE'');
    END IF;
...
```

or (probably better) `coalesce()` for both `NEW` and `OLD` records:

```
...
IF (TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
    IF (coalesce(NEW.name, '') <> coalesce(OLD.name, '')) THEN
        INSERT INTO log_test (type, table, field, old_val, new_val, user, event) VALUES (NEW.type,  TG_RELNAME, ''name'', OLD.name, NEW.name, NEW.user, ''UPDATE'');
    END IF;
...
```

Comment: You are totally right. I thought about the COALESCE function but missed the comparison.

Comment: Oh... What about integers and date values?

Comment: You can use `coalesce()` for any simple type. Only choose proper default value (last argument of the function).

Comment: It didn't work, as i received an error for numeric types when I try to update a row. Edit: Also Date types.

Comment: Should work. Add a new question with the code and error message.

Comment: I had to use coalesce(NEW/OLD.IntorDate::text,''); and it worked.